# How to call a function whose parameter is char ** from dll?

Tags: c#, char, dllimport

A function in dll is defined like this:

```
int DLLDIR nvcp_ep_to_buf(int ep_id, unsigned char** o_buf);
```

I want to call this function using `dllimport`, how could I declare this function in c#, and how can I call this function? If I call this function in c++, I allocate memory for `o_buf` and then call this function, it works.

Comment: Too little informations... what should this `o_buf` be? A two dimensional array of `unsigned char`? Because often when you see a `char**` as a parameter, it means that the memory is allocated by the called function, and not by the calling function.

Comment: `unsigned char**` does not define the interface sufficiently. `unsigned char**` could be many different things. Please consult the documentation. It will provide the missing details.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I struggled 2 days because of this problem but still can not solve it, I'd like to provide more details here:      o_buf is a pointer to an array of char. I want to know if i can use Intptr to bring the o_buf back, and I set the value of o_buf to a char *p; and then I can traverse p by the index. But I don't know how can I get the value of Intptr  which is a pointer to something in the memory.  Anyone can give me some specific code to solve this?